# Library linked to a library which itself is linked to an application -> undefined reference

Tags: c++, cmake, linker-errors, static-linking

I am looking at my problem for hours and I am stuck...

I have a library **lib_1** with function **`getNumber()`**.
Then I have a library **lib_2** with function **`addNumbers()`**.
`addNumbers()` calls `getNumber()` from lib_1.

My CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_library( lib_1 STATIC IMPORTED )
set_target_properties(lib_1 PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION path_to_lib_1)

add_library( lib_2 STATIC lib2.cpp )
target_link_libraries( lib_2 lib_1 )
target_include_directories(lib_2 PUBLIC include )
```

lib_2 compiles just fine, also the unit tests which use `getNumber()` are working.

Then I want to link lib_2 to my application app.

```
add_library( lib_1 STATIC IMPORTED )
set_target_properties(lib_1 PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION path_to_lib_1)

add_library( lib_2 STATIC IMPORTED )
set_target_properties(lib_2 PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION path_to_lib_2)

add_executable(app my_source_files )
target_link_libraries(app lib_1 lib_2)
```

When I compile my app I get this well known error:
**In function `addNumbers()` from lib_2, undefined reference to `getNumber()`**

I really don't get it, why its an undefined reference??

And btw do I really need to link against lib_1 in my application when already linking to lib_2 which itself is statically linking to lib_1?

Comment: Order matters! If `lib_2` depends on `lib_1`, then `lib_2` must be *before* `lib_1` when linking.

Comment: "do I really need to link against lib_1 in my application when already linking to lib_2 which itself is statically linking to lib_1?" - Yes, you need. Unlike to *shared* libraries, *static* ones don't contain information about linked libraries.

Comment: Omfg, didn't think about ordering them ... Thanks, it's working now...

Answer (score 0):

So as one can see in comments, the solution is to have the correct order of statically linked libraries:

```
add_executable(app my_source_files )
target_link_libraries(app lib_2 lib_1)
```